# RStudio: Including multiple plots in one graph

Tags: r

[Data1 in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neFzJ.png)

I have the following plots in RStudio:

*plot(Data1$Year, Data1$UKAll16_64, pch = 16, cex = 0.5,type="l", col = "blue", main = "UNEMPLOYMENT RATES 16-64", xlab = "YEARS (YR)", ylab = "PERCENTAGE (%)")*

*plot(Data1$Year, Data1$UKFemale16_64, pch = 16, cex = 0.5,type="l", col = "red", main = "UNEMPLOYMENT RATES FEMALES 16-64 ", xlab = "YEARS (YR)", ylab = "PERCENTAGE (%)")*

*plot(Data1$Year, Data1$UKMale16_64, pch = 16, cex = 0.5,type="l", col = "orange", main = "UNEMPLOYMENT RATES MALES 16-64 ", xlab = "YEARS (YR)", ylab = "PERCENTAGE (%)")*

---

As I am fairly new to R and RStudio, I am still learning and wanting to know how to include all 3 in one graph. Any help would be very much appreciated!!

**Edit: I included my data set in the form I wanted on excel to give a visual example of what I am trying to accomplish on R Studio**

Comment: What do you mean by "one graph" are you imagining 3 separate graphs side by side or just a graph that has three sets of lines each corresponding to a different part of the data?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the confusion! I mean one graph that has three sets of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use lines on the second and third "plots". Use `lty` to change the line type and `lwd` to change the line width. Cex is not relevant when plotting lines.

```
plot(Data1$Year, Data1$UKAll16_64, lwd = 0.5,type="l",
     col = "blue", main = "UNEMPLOYMENT RATES 16-64",
     xlab = "YEARS (YR)", ylab = "PERCENTAGE (%)")

lines(Data1$Year, Data1$UKFemale16_64, col = "red", lty = 3, lwd = 2)

lines(Data1$Year, Data1$UKMale16_64, col = "orange", lty = 5, lwd = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I have done what you have told me and I have realised I have not been specific enough with what I wanted. As I realised from a question propped up by another comment. I desire to have one graph with 3 sets of lines inside of it. I hope that makes sense and I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you want to plot one over another ?

Comment: Hello! I have included a picture of what I am trying to accomplish. I hope that will help to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help!